# Paypal IPN - How to get values of option_selection in listener?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

IPN sends me the option_selection1 value, but I think my listener cannot email me those values because they're urls.

In the html form, the buyer enters his optins in the text feild. And IPN sends this to the listener.

The job of my listener is to get the data and email me the details.

Problem is: I get the emails with all correct details but without the selection values.

Here is the form:

```html
Your website url:<br>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="website">
<input type="text" name="os0" size="30" required><br><br>
Your fb page url:<br>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="fb">
<input type="text" name="os1" size="30" required>
```

And here's the listener:

```html
<?php


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use: 
// $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item = $_POST['item_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$total = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$website = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$fb = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['custom'];
$id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$time = $_POST['payment_date'];



if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR
} 

else 
{
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) 
            {
                $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
                    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
                        {
                            // check the payment_status is Completed
                            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
                            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                            // process payment

$mail_From = "From: noreply@domainname.com/";
$mail_To = "my@gmail.com";
$mail_Subject = "New Order Received";
$mail_Body = '';

$emailtext = '

New Order Received
-------------------------
Item: '.$item.'
Quantity: '.$quantity.'
Total paid: $ '.$total.'

Website: '.$website.'
fb: '.$fb.'


Buyer Information:
-------------------------
First Name: '.$firstname.'
Last Name: '.$lastname.'
Email: '.$email.'

-------------------------
Transaction ID: '.$id.'
Time: '.$time.'

';

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $emailtext . "\n\n" . $mail_Body, $mail_From);

                        }
            }
}

?>
```

And this is the message that IPN sends to the listener:

```html
&option_selection1=http://www.testwebsite.com/home.html&option_selection2=http://www.facebook.com/testpage&option_name1=websitel&option_name2=fb
```

Comment: Can you add the code your are using to extract the IPN vars and send them via e-mail ?

Comment: @antoniom here you go.

Comment: @Biswajit where is `$squeeze` being defined?

Comment: @Mark Mistake, edited but still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This will prepare everything in a $cart_items array so that you can loop through the items and pull out the data you need accordingly.

```
$i = 1;
$cart_items = array();   
while(isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]))   
{   
    $item_number = isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_number' . $i] : '';   
    $item_name = isset($_POST['item_name' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_name' . $i] : '';   
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity' . $i]) ? $_POST['quantity' . $i] : '';  
    $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_handling = isset($_POST['mc_handling' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_handling' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_shipping = isset($_POST['mc_shipping' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_shipping' . $i] : 0;
    $custom = isset($_POST['custom' . $i]) ? $_POST['custom' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name1 = isset($_POST['option_name1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection1 = isset($_POST['option_selection1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name2 = isset($_POST['option_name2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name2_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection2 = isset($_POST['option_selection2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection2_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name3 = isset($_POST['option_name3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name3_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection3 = isset($_POST['option_selection3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection3_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name4 = isset($_POST['option_name4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name4_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection4 = isset($_POST['option_selection4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection4_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name5 = isset($_POST['option_name5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name5_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection5 = isset($_POST['option_selection5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection5_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name6 = isset($_POST['option_name6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name6_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection6 = isset($_POST['option_selection6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection6_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name7 = isset($_POST['option_name7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name7_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection7 = isset($_POST['option_selection7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection7_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name8 = isset($_POST['option_name8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name8_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection8 = isset($_POST['option_selection8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection8_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name9 = isset($_POST['option_name9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name9_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection9 = isset($_POST['option_selection9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection9_' . $i] : '';

    $btn_id = isset($_POST['btn_id' . $i]) ? $_POST['btn_id' . $i] : '';

    $current_item = array(   
                           'item_number' => $item_number,   
                           'item_name' => $item_name,   
                           'quantity' => $quantity, 
                           'mc_gross' => $mc_gross, 
                           'mc_handling' => $mc_handling, 
                           'mc_shipping' => $mc_shipping, 
                           'custom' => $custom,   
                           'option_name1' => $option_name1,   
                           'option_selection1' => $option_selection1,   
                           'option_name2' => $option_name2,   
                           'option_selection2' => $option_selection2, 
                           'option_name3' => $option_name3, 
                           'option_selection3' => $option_selection3, 
                           'option_name4' => $option_name4, 
                           'option_selection4' => $option_selection4, 
                           'option_name5' => $option_name5, 
                           'option_selection5' => $option_selection5, 
                           'option_name6' => $option_name6, 
                           'option_selection6' => $option_selection6, 
                           'option_name7' => $option_name7, 
                           'option_selection7' => $option_selection7, 
                           'option_name8' => $option_name8, 
                           'option_selection8' => $option_selection8, 
                           'option_name9' => $option_name9, 
                           'option_selection9' => $option_selection9, 
                           'btn_id' => $btn_id
                          );   

    array_push($cart_items, $current_item);   
    $i++;   
}
```